# Defer Initialization for Plugin Runtime not working

Tags: react-native, branch.io

I've followed the guide to `Defer Initialization for Plugin Runtime` but it's `not working on iOS`, on Android it's working perfectly. I've added the `branch.json` file to my project, and make sure it's existed on `Copy Bundle Resources phase`.
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native#defer-initialization-for-plugin-runtime

Does anyone have any idea? Please help. Thank you so much!

### Steps to reproduce

- Trigger the deep link flow by open the deep link URL.
- The App is opened from a cold start.
- branch.subscribe({}) not called so I can't get data from the URL

### Expected behavior

- Data received on branch.subscribe({}) from cold start

### SDK Version

- react-native-branch@6.0.0
- react-native@0.72.3

### OS

- iOS 17

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has this issue please delete your `branch.json` file and the issue will be gone. Very annoying when you do the rest following the guide and you have an issue. Can't understand!